# No Create Order endpoint, but create order request is an object available?

Tags: square-connect

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#type-createorderrequest

In the documentation for square, there's a few "dangling items". Specifically, there's a "CreateOrderRequest" and other related items, and they make reference to a "create order" endpoint, but no such endpoint exists in the documentation.

How do I work with this endpoint, and does it really exist?

Comment: That was a mistake, there is not currently a create order endpoint.

Comment: In that case, what is the flow for a typical purchase?

Comment: How do you mean? Generally you just generate a card nonce and then charge it.

Comment: Let me phrase it more concretely because my use case is weird: Is there any way to track orders and the like within square? I am interested in using it to run a service business, like a dry cleaner, and would need to track incoming and outgoing orders, as well as whether or not it has been paid for.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't what our current order functinoality can provide